# Should I use "teamo" or "skipo"?

Tags: word-choice

If I want to speak about the team of a project, should I use *teamo* or *skipo*?

I know that *teamo* is originally for a group with the same objective in a sport, while *skipo* is for every kind of group of people working together.

Would it be an error to use *teamo* for the group of people behind a project, as in *La teamo de Amikumu*? I have tried both, and in practice, *teamo* is more understood, even if the team has nothing to do with sports.

Answer (score 15):

It's very common and perfectly OK to use *teamo* as a synonym for *skipo*.

Look up the use of "teamo" at [tekstaro.com](http://tekstaro.com/). It seems *most* uses in the magazine *Monato* are nothing to do with sport, and in *La Ondo de Esperanto* (published in Russia) there are more references to sport, but also "la redakcia teamo", "la pariza teamo de UEA", etc.

Answer (score 11):

I would use *skipo*, as this is technically the correct meaning you want.

I personally consider the use of *teamo* an Anglicism. English has only one word for both concepts: *team*. So people get confused. But it's not like that in, say, Bulgarian:

> - *отбор* = *teamo*
> - *екип* = *skipo* (which also sounds very similar, like: *ekip*)

---

Mi uzus *skipo*, ĉar fakte tiu estas la signifo, kiun vi celas.

Persone, mi kredas, ke la uzo de *teamo* etas anglismo. La angla havas nur unu vorton por la du signifoj: *team*. Do parolantoj konfuziĝas. Sed en aliaj lingvoj, kiel en la bulgara, tio estas malsama:

> - *отбор* = *teamo*
> - *екип* = *skipo* (kiun oni elparolas tre simile: *ekip*)

Comment: For what it's worth, I picked up the word *teamo* in this broader sense from someone who is not a native English speaker, and neither does he live in an English-speaking area.

Answer (score 1):

An additional source:

https://languagedrops.com/word/en/english/esperanto/translate/night_shift/

Perhaps not authoritative but can serve as an example of the use of 'skipo' in a work environment.

Answer (score 0):

PIV ends its definition of [*skipo*](http://vortaro.net/#skipo) with

> *…k eventuale alternanta kun alia simila grupo*

So I'm inclined to think *skipo* as a shift in work. *La malsanulejo funkcias tagnokte en tri skipoj*.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. In general, if you have competing roots that are not official/Fundamentaj, you can check some dictionaries (prioritizing the more authoritative ones), for example using [Vikia Vortaro](http://www.kono.be/vivo/).

Then, a look to [bonalingvo.net](http://bonalingvo.net/index.php/Simplaj_samsignifaj_vortoj_-_listoj) can help decide if you really need a new non-official root for that.

Having done that, I'd suggest you go for *team-o*. It feels more general and [the definition](http://vortaro.net/#teamo) en PIV includes *skip-o* as synonym.